# How to get sum of counted rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table where i keep call center inquiries please see table below

```
    log_id call_date   call_time agent_name agent_id customer_name nature_of_inquiry
    1       2009-01-13   12:24:01  sam       a1       George        balance inquiry
    2       2009-01-13   03:01:10  james     a2       Ann           account opening
    3       2009-02-14   09:24:01  Lucy      a3       Paul          account opening
    4       2009-02-15   09:50:01  Lucy      a3       Luke          account opening
    5       2009-02-14   10:24:01  Lucy      a3       jill          account opening
```

i would like to run a query that selects  the number of calls by the agent if you query by agent name for instance like the table below,

```
    log_id call_date  call_time agent_name agent_id customer_name nature_of_inquiry no_of_calls

    3      2009-02-14   09:24:01  Lucy       a3        Paul         account opening
    4      2009-02-15   09:50:01  Lucy       a3        Luke         account opening
    5      2009-02-14   10:24:01  Lucy       a3        jill         account opening      3
```

This is the query am currently using

```
    SELECT log_id,call_date,  call_time, agent_name, agent_id ,customer_name ,nature_of_inquiry, SUM( counted) as no_of_calls
    FROM (
    (
    SELECT count( * ) AS counted, log_id ,call_date,  call_time, agent_name agent_id customer_name ,nature_of_inquiry
    FROM callcenter
        WHERE agentname = 'lucy'
        GROUP BY log_id) AS b )
        GROUP BY agent_name
```

Comment: how are you trying to show '3' in front of log_id = 5?

Answer (score 1):

```
select agent_name, count(*) as callcount
from callcenter
where agent_name = 'lucy'
group by agent_name
```

Comment: the query doesnot give sum of the count

Comment: log_id call_date call_time customer_name nature_of_inquiry no_of_calls

3      2009-02-14   09:24:01  Paul         account opening      
4      2009-02-15   09:50:01  Luke         account opening      
5      2009-02-14   10:24:01  jill         account opening      3

Answer (score 0):

Log id is unique so you do not need to group by it - it is pointless.  Also, if you use group by, you cannot take any field without aggregate function (like SUM, MIN etc). The reason is as follows:
Imagine you have 3 rows:

```
log_id call_date  call_time agent_name agent_id customer_name nature_of_inquiry no_of_calls

3      2009-02-14   09:24:01  Lucy       a3        Paul         account opening      4
4      2009-02-15   09:50:01  Lucy       a3        Luke         account opening      2
5      2009-02-14   10:24:01  Lucy       a3        jill         account opening      3
```

and you type something like

```
SELECT count(*), agent_name, SUM(no_of_calls), customer_name FROM table group by agent_name where agent_name="Lucy"
```

what would be your expected result?

Clearly there is no problem in defining what shoould be `count(*)` - it should be 3. What should be `agent_name`? The one you grouped by -- Lucy. No problems with `sum(no_of_calls)` - 4+2+3 = 9. However, here the problem begins: What should be `customer_name` ?! Paul, Luke or Jill ? you do not know this. In some database you get error if you try to do such query (for example postgresql). In MySQL I guess the first value is being returned (correct me if I am wrong). But this is not intuitive and you should avoid such queries.

That is why the correct query would be:

```
SELECT count(*), agent_name, SUM(no_of_calls) FROM table group by agent_name where agent_name="Lucy"
```

because all fields are either in group by or are wrapped in agregate function.

There might be an error in your question and you could just wanted to ask for calls to particular customers. In such case just use `customer_name` in group by, the logic remains the same. You can group by multiple values using `comma` as separator.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want to know the number of calls for each customer for each agent

```
SELECT call_date,  agent_name, agent_id ,customer_name , COUNT(customer_name) as no_of_calls
FROM callcenter
WHERE agent_name = 'lucy'
GROUP BY call_date, customer_name
```

If you need to show the data from more than one agent, then you group by agent_name, customer_name.

Comment: see my post why your query is "invalid" (in example, what should be the call_date in your opinion for lucy?) .

Comment: I am not sure why the query is wrong since there is no mention of call date. However I have added an additional GROUP BY on call_date if you need to show the totals by call_date too.

Comment: 26th character from the left until 34th character. What is written there?

Comment: It is the call_time column, what is the problem with it?

Comment: if you have 3 rows, which after group by are agregated to 1, then 3 different time stamps must be agregated to 1 - but you cannot do it without agregate function. that is why you cannot include call_time, because you are not able to determine the result of agregating 3 different call_time values into 1 value

Comment: I left the column there so that I do not change your original query, the call_time, nature_of_inquiry and log_id columns are indeterminate for this particular query. The agent_name, and agent_id columns will have the same values for all returned rows

Comment: leaving these columns in the query is actually error about which I am talking about.

Comment: I have updated the query to remove the infringing columns. Thanks for making that clear